# Drupal 8 multiple sub domains using same Database and different design

Tags: drupal, subdomain, drupal-multi-domain

Requirement is multiple sub domains using same Database and different design
For example my main site URL is `www.mysite.com`.
My requirement is
`www.sub1.mysite.com
 www.sub2.mysite.com
 www.sub3.mysite.com`

I also tried [Drupal Domain](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain)

I am using drupal 8.6.

How can I achieve this requirement.

Comment: Do you want to reuse same drupal setup for all domains ?

Comment: yes, but this is `www.mysite.com` parent website and all others are child. all sub domains have different design.

Comment: you can get idea from here `http://www.uol.edu.pk/` this is parent web site and these are `http://isb.uol.edu.pk/` `http://sgd.uol.edu.pk/` `http://chem.uol.edu.pk/` subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement multi-site structure of DRUPAL 8 like this.

```
-- core
-- modules
   -- contrib
   -- custom
-- themes
   -- contrib
   -- custom
-- sites
   -- site1
         -- modules
            -- custom
            -- contrib
         -- themes
            -- custom
            -- contrib
         -- files
   -- site2
         -- modules
            -- custom
            -- contrib
         -- themes
            -- custom
            -- contrib
        -- files
   -- site3
         -- modules
            -- custom
            -- contrib
         -- themes
            -- custom
            -- contrib
        -- files
```

For reference, please check this link i.e. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multisite/multisite-folder-structure-in-drupal-8

> For more technical articles or help, have a look at http://etutorialz.com

Comment: Can we use Single database for multi-site?. In documentation they states that `It is assumed that every site has its own database and code is shared as shown below`.

Comment: No that would not be possible with this way. 
For that you have to use https://www.drupal.org/project/domain . It's quite complicated but feasible.

Comment: I tried this but can't get success. I am not know how to configure this module.

Comment: Please have a look at this video i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_rP74-GFFQ

If it helps than mark my answer as solution.

Comment: If this answer helped you than plz mark my answer as solution.